# Spacing around symbols lowered using `\raisebox` in math mode doesn't always look nice---how to fix?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to denote some type of function application using a small circle:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand*{\smallcirc}{\scalebox{0.4}{$\circ$}}
\newcommand*{\smallcirclow}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\smallcirc}}
\newcommand*{\apf}{{\smallcirclow}}
\newcommand*{\apfpunct}{\mathpunct{\smallcirclow}}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{matrix}
      &f \apf x &f \apf [x] &\mathtt{f} \apf x &\mathtt{f} \apf [x] \\
      &f \apfpunct x &f \apfpunct [x] &\mathtt{f} \apfpunct x &\mathtt{f} \apfpunct [x]
    \end{matrix}
  \]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output (red and green boxes have been added in manually by me):

[image]

I have put red boxes around bits of the output with problematic spacing. We see that `\mathpunct`'s usage fixes the spacing around `f \apf x`, but then introduces problems around `f \apfpunct [x]`. I have a put green box around a bit of the output which also looks weird to me (i.e. both `\mathpunct` and no `\mathpunct` look kind of weird).

Perhaps my sense of spacing regarding what is "correct" is off? If not, how can I systematically describe what I am seeing, and what's the approach to achieving a nice look?

Comment: You could define it as `\mathpunct` instead of `\mathord`. But wouldn't `\newcommand*{\apf}{\boldsymbol{.}}` be much easier?

Comment: @campa It would indeed be easier. The issue with that is that I need another symbol which is based on `\circ` ("hollow bullet"?). So `\boldsymbol{.}` would only work for the solid bullet. Let me try out `\mathpunct`.

Comment: @campa So `\mathpunct` looks nicer, except for the `\mathtt{f}` examples, which now have a weird amount of space between the dot and the `[`?

Comment: Sorry but I won't try to guess. IMO the best solution for `.` is using `\boldsymbol`. If  you have a question about some symbol based on `\circ` instead, then please update your question and ask _that_.

Comment: @campa I did as you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. There is some space in the second instance in the top row, because the bracket sits a bit right from the bounding box boundary, which doesn't happen for “x”. For sure `\mathpunct` is the weakest candidate.

Comment: @egreg is there a way to stop having the circle coming way too close to the `x` when not using `mathpunct`?

Comment: This undoubtedly just proves that I'm not a mathematician, but ... what is the meaning of this circle that you're designating it as punctuation rather than using a subscript?

Comment: @barbarabeeton :p It's meant to be notation for application of prefix functions to their arguments. Usually, we'd write `f(x)`, but if you have something like `d(e(f(g(h(x)))))` it can become a bit cumbersome. Instead we can write `d.e.f.g.h.x` (assume that `.` is right associative). This notation is quite rare: I don't know if anyone uses it outside some computer science applications. A related notation where a space is used (so `d e f g h x`) is slightly less rare, I think.